# java.util.logging.Logger doesn't write in the log file on Linux

Tags: java, logging

What I am working on is a component program which is supposed to be run on Linux server (CentOS7). I used java.util.logging.Logger and its FileHandler to create a log file and append logs.

It beautifully works on the local server which is Tomcat7 on eclipse. But it only creates a log file and doesn't write any logs on it when run on the Linux server. I have also made the parent directory of the component have all permission. But it doesn't give any changes.

What i am confused is that it definitely creates a log file. My codes are the below.

```
private final Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
private FileHandler fileHandler;

public String run(){

    try {
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("component.log", true);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        .....
    }

    logger.info("==== component start ====");

    .............
    .............

    fileHandler.close();

    return "....";
}
```

Comment: Can you try to write the log files to a sync mount? Maybe it is some OS caching.

Comment: thank you, but I don't see what you mean

Comment: With an async mount the OS doesn't write changes to a file immediately, but keeps them in memory. A partition mounted as synchronous will, although it is of course slower.

Comment: the log file is to be created in the same directory as the component running. So it had nothing to do with mounting i think.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, change your file name to ["component%u.log"](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html).  You might be trying to open multiple file handlers to the same file depending on how this code is run.